# contentInsetLeft not working on toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I have been looking for a solution for this problem on stackoverflow almost the whole day, but I couldn't find a solution.

I have a custom toolbar built up like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00a7e0"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
```

Now currently I have a small left margin on the toolbar like this:

[image: Screenshot of toolbar]

It should now be possible to remove this left margin with contentInsetLeft (or -Start), what I already included in the xml of the toolbar. Unfortunately the left margin is still here on my Samsung S7 running Android 6.0. I tried every possible solution but it doesn't change. Strangely, the left margin disappears when running the application on an older device with Android 4.1.2

Does someone have a solution?

EDIT: I maybe have to mention, that I am using the Ionic Framework for the core of the application. I am though working on a Ionic plugin, which is native android.

Comment: Initially I had android:contentInsetLeft="72dp", that was a mistake. It should be android:contentInsetLeft="0dp" but still the left margin is there.

Comment: Use android:contentInsetStart="0dp". That will work